# AngularJS dynamic form input with fieldset via ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Please click on the demo below

www.jsfiddle.net/rnnb32rm/1370

> My problem is: "Add input" is working fine. But whenever i invoke "Add
>   Fields", the subsequent field will be sync with the first one. I want
>   the subsequent to be filled with only one input. Stuck for hours already. Please guide!

Picture to illustrate:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

May be help you.

```js
var app = angular.module("app",[]);

app.controller("MyCtrl" , function($scope){
  
   $scope.data ={
       items:[{ name:"",family:"",age:""}]
   };
  
  $scope.addRow = function(index){
    var item = { name:"",family:"",age:""};
       if($scope.data.items.length <= index+1){
            $scope.data.items.splice(index+1,0,item);
        }
    };
  
  $scope.deleteRow = function($event,item){
  var index = $scope.data.items.indexOf(item);
    if($event.which == 1)
       $scope.data.items.splice(index,1);
    }
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   <table>
     <tr ng-repeat="name in data.items track by $index">
        <td> <input type="text" ng-model="data.items[$index].name"></td>
         <td> <input type="text" ng-model="data.items[$index].family"></td>
          <td> <input type="text" ng-model="data.items[$index].age"></td>
        <td> <input type="button" ng-click="addRow($index)" value="Add" ng-show="$last"></td>
        <td> <input type="button" ng-click="deleteRow($event,name)" value="Delete" ng-show="$index != 0"></td>
     </tr>
   </table> 
    <span>{{data|json}}</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I answered this the first time you posted this question, but you deleted it.

You only have one `choices` array, and you are using it over and over:

```
$scope.addNewChoice = function() {
    // ...
    // Same array each time
    $scope.choices.push({'id':'choice'+newItemNo});
};

<fieldset  data-ng-repeat="choice in choices2">
    <div  data-ng-repeat="choice in choices "> <!-- Same array each time -->
```

You probably want one array for each entry in the `choices2` array.

Also, both of your `ng-repeat` elements use the same variable name (`choice`) which is confusing.